# SQLite create a new record if it doesn't exist

Tags: sql, ios, sqlite

Hey so I'm trying to create a new record based on one which already exists, but I'm having trouble ensuring that this record doesn't already exist. The database stores details of transactions and has a field for whether it repeats.

I'm generating the new dates using

```
SELECT datetime(transactions.date, '+'||repeattransactions.interval||' days') 
AS 'newdate' FROM transactions, repeattransactions WHERE 
transactions.repeat = repeattransactions.id
```

Initially I'd like to use `SELECT` instead of `INSERT` just for debugging purposes. I've tried to do something with `GROUP BY` or `COUNT(*)` but the exact logic is eluding me. So for instance I've tried

```
SELECT * FROM transactions, (SELECT transactions.id, payee, category, amount, 
fromaccount, repeat, datetime(transactions.date, 
'+'||repeattransactions.interval||' days') AS 'date' FROM transactions,
repeattransactions WHERE transactions.repeat = repeattransactions.id)
```

but this obviously treats the two tables as though they were joined, it doesn't append the records to the bottom of the table which would let me group.

I've been struggling for days so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT:
The docs say "The ON CONFLICT clause applies to UNIQUE and NOT NULL constraints". I can't have a unique constraint on the table by definition as I have to create the exact same record for a new transaction with just a new date. Or have I misinterpreted this?

EDIT2:

```
id        payee     repeat      date
1         jifoda    7           15/09/2011
2         jifoda    7           22/09/2011  <-- allowed as date different within subset
3         grefa     1           15/09/2011  <-- allowed as only date is not-unique
4         grefa     1           15/09/2011  <-- not allowed! exactly same as id 3
```

Comment: What is your criteria to check for "this record already exists"? You need to create unique constraint based on this criteria.

Comment: the unique constraint has to be that all columns can be non-unique but if all columns except `date` are the same as another record then the `date` column has to be unique in the subset of records which have all columns except `date`. If that makes any sense at all...

Comment: that totally doesn't make any sense. See edit 2 above.

Comment: Can't you define compound primary key in SQLite? Like PRIMARY KEY (field1, field2, ..., date)? This way you can use MERGE command, which inserts new record, if primary key doesn't match and updates record, if primary key matches. If you include all fields into key, then it just doesn't update anything.

Comment: SQLite doesn't have a MERGE command.

Comment: Ok i'm investigating the composite primary key and it's leading somewhere so thanks. Wanna put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

SQLite has special DDL statement for duplicates. Like:

```
create table test(a TEXT UNIQUE ON CONFLICT IGNORE);
insert into test values (1);
insert into test values (1);
select count(*) from test;
1
```

It can be also `ON CONFLICT REPLACE`. See docs.

Comment: see @Arvo's text. Also, you could create a synthetic ID, say, of concatenated transaction_id and date?